# Javascript class model: calling class function from dialog definition

Tags: javascript

I'm using John Resig's class model (http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) and have this question:

In the class below I'm building a delete dialog. When the "yes" button is pressed I'd like to execute the `handleDeleteItem` function. How would I do that? I can't use "this.handleDeleteItem" since "this" refers to the dialog.

```
var bItem = Class.extend({
    init: function (type) {
        this.id = type + "-" + getNewId();
    },
    registerDelete: function () {
        var itemId = this.id;

        // Build Delete Dialog
        var deleteDialog = '<div id="' + itemId + '-delete-dialog" title="Delete Item?"><p><br/><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you want to delete this item?</p></div>';

        // Append dialog
        $('#b-main').append(deleteDialog);

        // Confirmation dialog
        $('#' + itemId + '-delete-dialog').dialog({
            buttons : {
                "Yes" : this.handleDeleteItem(),
                "No" : function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    },
    handleDeleteItem: function () {}
});
```

Comment: So, if `this.handleDeleteItem` is unresolved, is `bItem.handleDeleteItem` okay? Either way, `.handleDeleteItem()` returns undefined, which means you essentially bind "Yes" to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong. Try the following instead:

```
$('#' + itemId + '-delete-dialog').dialog({
    buttons : {
        "Yes" : this.handleDeleteItem.bind(this),
        "No" : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that I replaced `this.handleDeleteItem()` with `this.handleDeleteItem.bind(this)`.

1. When you do `this.handleDeleteItem()` you're calling `this.handleDeleteItem` and assigning its return value as the event listener for "Yes".
2. When you do `this.handleDeleteItem.bind(this)` you're assigning `this.handleDeleteItem` itself as the event listener for "Yes". The `.bind(this)` is used to ensure that the event listener has the correct `this` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the issue is that I can't call this.handleDeleteItem.bind(this) because the first 'this' refers to the dialog and thus the function definition is not found.

Comment: @user998066 Why would `this` point to the dialog? It's evaluated in the scope of `registerDelete`. Hence `this` would point to the instance, not the dialog. The way I see it `this.handleDeleteItem.bind(this)` should work as expected. Try it.

Comment: I realized that I was calling 'this.handleDeteItem' inside a click() function definition:

    $('#'+itemId).click(function() {...});

I ended up defining a variable for the object to save a reference to it and then calling the function of the variable, e.g.
var myItem = this;
then later:
myItem.handleDeleteItem();